# Como agrupar por Id sql server

Tags: sql-server

Tengo una consulta la cual suma los valores que son iguales siempre y cuando sean iguales (IdFactura, NombreProveedor) pero ahora quiero que desaparezcan los valores que son duplicados, pero al correr el query me manda el error

> Column 'FacturasPendientes.FechaFactura' is invalid in the select list
>   because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the
>   GROUP BY clause

La consulta que estoy haciendo es la siguiente, ya lo intente con .*

```
SELECT IdFactura,FechaFactura,a.CodigoProveedor,NombreProveedor,SUM(Total) Over(Partition by IdFactura, NombreProveedor) as Total,FechaDPP,FechaFinal,Pagado,Comentario,b.TipoDePago FROM FacturasPendientes a INNER JOIN CatalogoProveedores b 
ON a.CodigoProveedor = b.CodigoProveedor WHERE FechaDPP BETWEEN '2019-12-18 00:00:00.000' AND '2019-12-19 23:59:59.000' AND Pagado ='0' GROUP BY IdFactura
```

Comment: Tu error se debe a que no tienes en el GROUP BY el campo de FechaFactura y todos los demas campos

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El error es porque te sobra el group by, puesto que estas utilizando una función de ventana.

Además ese filtro de fechas, puede no ser del todo correcto, porque si tienes una factura el 2019-12-19 23:59:59.997 que es un rango válido para un datetime, no te vendría. Puedes cambiarlo por:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT 
    IdFactura
  , FechaFactura
  , a.CodigoProveedor
  , NombreProveedor
  , SUM(Total) Over(Partition by IdFactura, NombreProveedor) as Total
  , FechaDPP
  , FechaFinal
  , Pagado
  , Comentario
  , b.TipoDePago 
FROM FacturasPendientes a INNER JOIN CatalogoProveedores b 
    ON a.CodigoProveedor = b.CodigoProveedor 
WHERE FechaDPP >= '2019-12-18 00:00:00.000' AND FechaDPP < '2019-12-20 00:00:00.000' 
AND Pagado ='0'
```

Otra opción es utilizar group by en vez de distinct y Over.

Comment: Funciono muy bien ... la verdad, es lo que buscaba pensaba que tenia que hacer una tonelada de code en vb6 para hacer esto... gracias totales